# Argon2i password hash algorithm is not working in php?

Tags: php, php-password-hash, argon2-ffi

I am learning api development with php now. While experimenting the password hashing i came up with a problem.

Initally i used bcrypt algorithm, it successfully works, but when i tried `Argon2i` or `Argon2id` it throws an error.

```
public function test_hash() {
    if(isset($this->_request['pass'])) {
        $hash = password_hash($this->_request['pass'], '2y', array('cost' => 10));
        
        $input = "password";

        if(password_verify($input, $hash)) {
            echo "True" . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "False" . "\n";
        }

        $data = array("password" => $this->_request['pass'], "hashed pwd" => $hash);
        $data = $this->json($data);

        $this->response($data, 200);
    }
}
```

for this :
`http://localhost/api/test_hash?pass=password`

I get resposnse as :

```
True
{
    "password": "password",
    "hashed pwd": "$2y$10$4M4qHHSN6S0y7h6xyW6XCuRNhW44xRFN5EjnHNTPZKzuBeXXHMe0e"
}
```

When i try Argon2i it doesn't works... i replaced the following line

```
$hash = password_hash($this->_request['pass'], 'argon2i');
```

i get response as...

> 500 Internal Server Error

I also checked for available algorithms...

```
php > $info = password_algos();
php > print_r($info);
Array
(
    [0] => 2y
    [1] => argon2i
    [2] => argon2id
)
```

Comment: When you get a 500 error the first ting to do is check the PHP Error log for some clues. Did you?

Comment: If `'2y'` is allowed in the parameter list, you must be using PHP 7.4 or >. So what OS are you using?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i use php 8.1.2 and i use linux.